# Lucene 'minimumNumberShouldMatch' fails parsing

Tags: lucene

I create simple boolean query with `org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.Builder`.

I also want to use minimumNumberShouldMatch there, to specify a minimum number of the optional BooleanClauses which must be satisfied:

```
    BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();

    builder.add(new TermQuery(new Term("field", "value1")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    builder.add(new TermQuery(new Term("field", "value2")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    builder.add(new TermQuery(new Term("field", "value3")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

    builder.setMinimumNumberShouldMatch(2);

    String queryString = builder.build().toString();
    System.out.println(queryString);
```

As a result, I get this query string:

```
(field:value1 field:value2 field:value3)~2
```

I want this query to return documents if at least two clauses are satisfying.

---

But I face a problem during parsing this query:

```
new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_7_7_1.toString(), new ClassicAnalyzer()).parse(queryString);
```

throws following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Cannot parse '(field:value1 field:value2 field:value3)~2': Encountered " <FUZZY_SLOP> "~2 "" at line 1, column 40.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    <AND> ...
    <OR> ...
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    "^" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <NUMBER> ...

    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:114)
    at ....lucene.common.BaseLuceneConnection.main(BaseLuceneConnection.java:101)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Encountered " <FUZZY_SLOP> "~2 "" at line 1, column 40.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    <AND> ...
    <OR> ...
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    "^" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <NUMBER> ...

    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.generateParseException(QueryParser.java:931)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.jj_consume_token(QueryParser.java:813)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:216)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:109)
    ... 1 more
```

I also tried to run this query with Luke, but getting the same error there.

Please, tell me, why this query can't be parsed, although it was built using appropriate tool.

Answer (score 1):

`Query.toString()` is not serialization, there is no guarantee that the query passed back will be parseable by the `QueryParser`. It is intended to pass back something reasonably human-readable, for debugging purposes.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, since you have already built perfectly acceptable BooleanQuery, but you should **never** do something like this: `QueryParser.parse(query.toString())`

QueryParser does not support minimumNumberShouldMatch. Search with your BooleanQuery.